# Correct usage of IF condition with various tenses

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Which one would be the correct form for this context?
This situation is a Hypothetical and takes place in future.

> He would be killed when he **arrives** in London.
>
> OR
>
> He would be killed when he **arrived** in London.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be He would be killed when he arrives in London.

Or He will be killed when he arrives in London.

Would is a conditional modal verb.
It would be hot when he leaves the plain in Texas after his trip tomorrow. The condition is his arrival then. The tense of what happens then belongs to that as if it were now.

If this is last years plan that failed you would be telling it as "Our plan was that He would be killed when he arrived in London." There the tense belongs to back then.

Comment: Thx Elliot.., Perfect...!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Wish I knew about the vote. Maybe I spoiled his London plans.